# Mobile vs Large Image Sizes

Tags: css, image, twitter-bootstrap

I am building a web site using Bootstrap 4. One area that I do not understand are images. In my page, I have an image at the top. The picture file is 640x480. When someone views this on a laptop (large devices and up), I want the picture to appear as a maximum of 320px tall. But, I want to use the full 640 pixels of width. At the same time, because this is a high-resolution photo, I do not want to stretch or horizontally repeat the image.

At the same time, on a phone (medium devices and down), I want the picture to fill the width of the screen and the height to scale appropriately.

I have a Bootply [here](http://www.bootply.com/4FY6YL8Fpz). My current html is this

```
<div class="container">
  <img alt="testing" src="http://i1.tribune.com.pk/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/562140-BillGatesAFP-1371012273-193-640x480.jpg" class="img-rounded banner-img"> 

  <!-- image from: https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiAkO-psbvMAhVD2D4KHYX7BwMQjB0IBg&url=http%3A%2F%2Ftribune.com.pk%2Fstory%2F562140%2Fhealthcare-philanthropy-bill-gates-offers-help-to-eradicate-diseases%2F&psig=AFQjCNFGhsgyR1bSKdIqXKywX49HXAWi3A&ust=1462278274506113 -->  
</div>
```

The main stuff is in the CSS which looks like this:

```
.banner-img {
    max-height:320px;
}

@media (max-width: 544px) {
    .banner-img {
        height: auto; 
        max-height:320px; 
        width:auto; 
        max-width:100%;        
    }
}
```

Responsively using photographs seems weird to me. I feel like I want to give the image width precedence on larger screens. On smaller screens, it seems like I need to use the image height as the precedence. Yet, on larger screens, it seems like some cropping needs to happen, yet I'm not sure how to do that with CSS. At the same time, I do not want to have two separate images due to performance concerns.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: Why don't you use the image as `background-image` of a container using `background-size: cover`? You can set you sizes on the container and the image will always fill up the container (automatically cropped).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this.

```css
#BannerIMG{
  /*add this for caption*/
 display: table;

 width:100%;
  /*change the height if requierd*/
 height:320px;
 background:no-repeat;
 background-size: 100% auto;
 background-image:url(http://i1.tribune.com.pk/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/562140-BillGatesAFP-1371012273-193-640x480.jpg);
}

#caption{
  display: table-cell;
  color:white;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<!-- You can use different css files for large or small screens
<link href="SmallStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" media="(max-width: 400px)">
    <link href="LargeStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" media="(min-width: 400px)">
-->

<div class="container">
  <div id="BannerIMG"><span id="caption"><center>Optional Caption</center></span></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
@media (max-width: 544px) {
```

by

```
@media (min-width: 544px) {
```

Make you default class for mobile first, then overwite it for larger screen, like the bootstrap grid.
Then, use img-responsive class from bootstrap to make your image responsive.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the image as background-image of a container using `background-size: cover;`? You can set you sizes on the container and the image will always fill up the container (automatically cropped).

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="iamge-item" style="background-image: url("http://i1.tribune.com.pk/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/562140-BillGatesAFP-1371012273-193-640x480.jpg"> 
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.image-item {
    background-image: url("/path/to/your/image.jpg"); /* if not defined inline*/
    background-size: cover; /* to cover the container*/
    background-position: 50% 50%; /* to center the image */
    width: 640px;
    height: 320px;
}

@media (max-width: 544px) {
    .image-item { width: 100%; }
}
```

---

If this isn't an option for you, I would position the image absolute:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="image-wrapper">
        <img alt="testing" src="http://i1.tribune.com.pk/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/562140-BillGatesAFP-1371012273-193-640x480.jpg" class="img-rounded banner-img">
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.image-wrapper {
    width: 640px;
    height: 320px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
.image-wrapper > .banner-img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%; left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* to center it again */
}

@media (max-width: 544px) {
    .image-wrapper { width: 100%; }
}
```